# .NET's similar to PHP's PDO?

Tags: c#, php, database, pdo

I'm coming from PHP and eventually I will dive into things like NHibernate or Microsoft Entity Framework, but for now I would really just like something simple like PHP's PDO for connecting to a database:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database');
$db->exec('delete from users');
```

PDO abstracts the connection on the database (whatever it is, not just sqlite) and provides some common methods to execute prepared statements and stuff. Is there something this simple in .NET?

obs: I just started with C# so if you could be very specific on how to link the libraries to the project or other setup steps (if needed) I would really appreciate it (: ~ I'm using VS2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET the technology that allows you to query a relational database is called [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Your connection string comes here"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM users";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In this example I have used the ADO.NET provider for SQLite which you could [`download from here`](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

So the first step here would be for you to download the managed provider for .NET from the aforementioned website.

The next step is to reference the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` assembly in your project by right clicking the References node in the solution explorer and choosing the assembly. Be careful as there are both x86 and x64 assemblies for SQLite, so make sure to pick the one that's most appropriate for your target architecture.

Once you have referenced the assembly, the `SQLiteConnection` type which I have shown in my example and which is overriding the ADO.NET base classes will be available to your code and you could use it directly to query the database. Don't forget to add a `using System.Data.SQLite;` directive to your file to bring those classes into scope, once you have referenced the assembly.

If you don't want to go through all the pain of downloading, extracting, etc... the SQLite dependency you could simply install the [System.Data.SQLite NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) that's available.

Understanding how ADO.NET works is the basis for understanding how ORM frameworks such as NHibernate and Entity Framework work in the future, so it's really important to start with the basics.

Comment: this was even better than what i was hoping for. this nuGet thing is awesome :D

Comment: Just adding some piece of information: this library won't work in VS's debug mode unless you specify a Build platform target (e.g. x86) in the project properties :p

Answer (score 0):

```
PDO in dotNET
[enter link description here][1]
  [1]: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SDO_dotNET/1.0.2


    The SDO_dotNET Class Library is a high level wrapper around the ODBC, OLEDB, SQLServer and SQLite.

Example:
using SqlDB;

/******************************************************************
Sql Server
*******************************************************************/

string server      = @"INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS";
string database = "DEMODB";
string username = "sa";
string password = "";

string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + "; Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password + "";
SDO db_conn = new SDO(connectionString);

Console.WriteLine("isConnected: " + db_conn.isConnected());
if (db_conn == null || !db_conn.isConnected())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connessione non valida.");
    return;
}

string sql = "SELECT ID, Message FROM Logs ORDER BY IDLic;";
DataTable dtLogs = db_conn.SelectTable(sql);

if (dtLogs == null || dtLogs.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;

// Loop with the foreach keyword.
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLogs.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + dr["Message"].ToString().Trim());
}



/******************************************************************
SQLite
*******************************************************************/

string database = @"C:\Users\Utente\mydb.sqlite";

string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + database + "; Version=3; New=True; Compress=True;"; // local
SDO db_conn = new SDO(connectionString);

Console.WriteLine("isConnected: " + db_conn.isConnected());
if (db_conn == null || !db_conn.isConnected())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connessione non valida.");
    return;
}

string sql = "SELECT firstname, surname FROM users ORDER BY firstname;";
DataTable dtLogs = db_conn.SelectTable(sql);

if (dtLogs == null || dtLogs.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;

// Loop with the foreach keyword.
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLogs.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dr["firstname"].ToString().Trim() + " " + dr["surname"].ToString().Trim());
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Would you like to give some explanation of your code? You might a right answer but please provide some explanation of your code with the answer also.